# Python vlc, taking snapshots does not work

Tags: python, vlc, rtsp

Есть код:

```
def get_screenshot():
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://#######')
    player.play()  # Включить воспроизведение с камеры в VLC
    time.sleep(5)
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, './screenshot.tmp.jpg', 0, 0)
```

После запуска получаю `Process finished with exit code 0`, т.е. вроде все норм

но в папке с проектом нет файла `screenshot.tmp.jpg`

Почему так? Если запустить в VLC плеере потом, то все работает

Может есть альтернативные способы получить скрин?